# Categories will only display links to posts

Tags: categories, posts

Hey I'm currently using the Titan theme for my website and I want each category to display each FULL posts for that particular category, but with my theme Titan this is not a option. I only get links for my categories. I don't know what pages and code to edit to change this. Right now I only get this when you click on a category.

http://femalerappers.net/category/patwa/

A temporary fix for me has been to create pages and use the [[ post # ]] code in each individual page to display what I want on each page.

Hope you can help so I can just use my categories and they automatically update on each category with full posts instead of just links.   Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Look in your theme's folder for a file called "category.php". Open it then look for something like this:

```
<span><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></span>
```

Place this right below it:

```
<p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
```

That will display an excerpt of each post below the title.

Comment: Small problem. No such file in my TITAN theme directory exists for category.php , but the theme I'm not using TWENTYTEN does show such a file. WTF? lol

Comment: So I have no file category.php to edit according to my ftp. Which is odd and don't see how I wouldn't.

Comment: it's perfectly fine not to have a category.php. Try adding it to either index.php or archive.php, or perhaps archives.php.

Comment: Thank you I wanted the full post, but I just replaced excerpt with content (Only 3 months wordpress experience here so just learning everything!). It was in archive.php .. This helped me so much you dun know!